# Adding a tab index to an AngularJS accordion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, accordion, tabbing

Hi I have an AngularJS accordion that I've created with the code below. I would like to add a tab index to the accordion such that someone can tab through all the li tags of the accordion.

```
            <accordion close-others="showOnlyOne">
                <accordion-group heading="{{group.name}}" ng-repeat="group in reportFiltered"  is-open="group.isThisOpen">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li ng-repeat="myObj in group.myObj">
                            <a ng-click="function(myObj.query)">{{myObj.name}}</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </accordion-group>
            </accordion>
```

I have tried doing things such:

```
tabIndex="item.index
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Furthermore, I also need a way to access the tabs contents/value once they are currently tabbed on...but thats my next issue.

UPDATE:

I got the tabbing to work with {{$index}} but now I need to do something with the current li tag that is being tabbed over..

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
tabindex="{{item.index}}"
```

Or even better

```
ng-attr-tabindex="{{item.index}}"
```

You also can access $index from ngRepeat

Comment: Would i attach this to the li tags? I tried the first one earlier and it didnt let me tab through `                        <li ng-repeat="myObj in group.myObj" ng-attr-tabindex="{{myObj.index}}">
                            <a ng-click="function(myObj.query)">{{myObj.name}}</a>
                        </li>`

Comment: You add it to the element you want to add tabindex to. You don't seen to have "item.index" in your scope, this should work with a valid variable

Comment: I got {{$index}} to work instead. I'm confused why the other way didn't work though.

Is there a way to select these tags by their tabindex?

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to do

Comment: Each of these li tags has a name. Let's say when the tab is on top of any of the li tags, I wanted to console.log or alert the {{myObj.name}} of the li tag that is currently tabbed on when the user hits the enter tab.

Comment: I tried adding a reportTabbed class to each of the li/a tags and then using focus like this mainPanel.find(".reportTabbed").focus(function(){
    var listItem = this;
    console.log(listItem);
 });
but it doesnt work as expected

Comment: You need the help of a directive to be able to bind the focus event to your li tabs